# Adding page specific JavaScript via SXA

Tags: sxa

How can I add Page specific javascript in SXA. I've done it using PlainHTML rendering, but what if my script is big and I want to call it from outside

Comment: Could you elaborate on using the page's body css class for a page-based solution? My organization is attempting to use url query parameters to customize text on a page and I'm struggling to find good information on how to utilize javascript on a page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I love this question because I have an answer. Not long ago I built a module for SXA that would do this. I may not have tested this on your version of SXA, but it should give you an idea how to do it.

Check out this [link](https://github.com/michaellwest/westco-sxa-extensions) for more details.

- I added a processor called **AddPlainIncludes** to pull items from the media library and add to the page. SXA comes with a class called `PlainInclude` that you can use.
- The processor looks for items in the media library, similar to a **Theme** but called **Asset**. The structure is similar but has additional properties for CDN.

I built the module so I could load scripts from a CDN.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```csharp
var urlInclude = new PlainInclude
{
    SortOrder = num,
    Name = plainIncludeItem.Name,
    Type = assetType,
    Content = urlContent
};
assetsList.Add(urlInclude);
```

Here is the processor:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.StringExtensions;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.IoC;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Bundler;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Configuration;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Pipelines.AssetService;

namespace Westco.XA.Foundation.Theming.Pipelines.AssetService
{
    public class AddPlainIncludes : AddAssetsProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(AssetsArgs args)
        {
            if (!IsSxaPage()) return;
            var assetConfiguration = AssetConfigurationReader.Read();

            var contextItem = Context.Item;
            if (contextItem == null) return;

            var siteItem = ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<IMultisiteContext>().GetSiteItem(contextItem);

            var settingsItem = siteItem?.Children["Settings"];
            if (settingsItem == null) return;

            var assetIds = new string[0];
            var siteAssetsIds = settingsItem[Templates.Page.Fields.AssociatedAssets]?.Split('|');
            var pageAssetsIds = contextItem[Templates.Page.Fields.AssociatedAssets]?.Split('|');

            if (siteAssetsIds != null && siteAssetsIds.Any())
            {
                assetIds = assetIds.Union(siteAssetsIds).ToArray();
            }

            if (pageAssetsIds != null && pageAssetsIds.Any())
            {
                assetIds = assetIds.Union(pageAssetsIds).ToArray();
            }

            if (!assetIds.Any()) return;

            var assetsList = new List<AssetInclude>();
            const int num = 0;

            var plainIncludeItems = contextItem.Axes.SelectItems($"/sitecore/media library//*[@@templateid='{Templates.PlainInclude.Id}']");
            if (!plainIncludeItems.Any()) return;

            foreach (var assetId in assetIds)
            {
                if (assetId.IsNullOrEmpty() || !ID.IsID(assetId)) continue;
                var plainIncludeItem = plainIncludeItems.FirstOrDefault(pii => pii.ID.ToString() == assetId);
                if (plainIncludeItem == null) continue;

                var mode = GetEnumFieldValue(plainIncludeItem.Fields[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.Mode]);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mode) || mode.Equals("Disabled", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;

                var assetTypeEx = (AssetTypeEx)Enum.Parse(typeof(AssetTypeEx), mode);
                var assetType = assetTypeEx == AssetTypeEx.Style ? AssetType.Style : AssetType.Script;

                var attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                if (!plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.SriHash].IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    attributes.Add("integrity", plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.SriHash]);
                }

                if (!plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.Cors].IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    attributes.Add("crossorigin", GetEnumFieldValue(plainIncludeItem.Fields[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.Cors]));
                }

                switch (assetTypeEx)
                {
                    case AssetTypeEx.ScriptAsync:
                        attributes.Add("async", "");
                        break;
                    case AssetTypeEx.ScriptDefer:
                        attributes.Add("defer", "");
                        break;
                }

                var url = plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.AssetUrl];
                var joinedAttributes = string.Join(" ",
                    attributes.Where(a => !a.Value.IsNullOrEmpty()).Select(a => $"{a.Key}=\"{a.Value}\""));
                joinedAttributes += string.Join(" ",
                    attributes.Where(a => a.Value.IsNullOrEmpty()).Select(a => $"{a.Key}"));

                var urlContent = GetUrlContent(assetType, url, joinedAttributes);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlContent)) continue;

                var urlInclude = new PlainInclude
                {
                    SortOrder = num,
                    Name = plainIncludeItem.Name,
                    Type = assetType,
                    Content = urlContent
                };
                assetsList.Add(urlInclude);

                var isFallbackEnabled = MainUtil.GetBool(plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.IsFallbackEnabled], false);
                var fallbackTest = plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.FallbackTest];
                if (isFallbackEnabled && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fallbackTest))
                {

                    var tagBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var script in ProcessAssets(plainIncludeItem, AssetType.Script,
                        assetConfiguration.ScriptsMode))
                    {
                        tagBuilder.Append(script);
                    }

                    foreach (var link in ProcessAssets(plainIncludeItem, AssetType.Style,
                        assetConfiguration.StylesMode))
                    {
                        tagBuilder.Append(link);
                    }

                    if (tagBuilder.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fallbackInclude = new PlainInclude
                        {
                            SortOrder = num,
                            Name = plainIncludeItem.Name + "-fallback",
                            Type = AssetType.Script,
                            Content = "<script>{0} || document.write('{1}')</script>".FormatWith(fallbackTest,
                                tagBuilder.ToString())
                        };
                        assetsList.Add(fallbackInclude);
                    }
                }

                var rawContent = GetRawContent(assetType, plainIncludeItem[Templates.PlainInclude.Fields.RawContent]);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawContent)) continue;

                var rawInclude = new PlainInclude
                {
                    SortOrder = num,
                    Name = plainIncludeItem.Name,
                    Type = assetType,
                    Content = rawContent
                };
                assetsList.Add(rawInclude);
            }

            if (assetsList.Any())
            {
                args.AssetsList.InsertRange(0, assetsList.ToArray());
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> ProcessAssets(Item plainIncludeItem, AssetType assetType, AssetServiceMode serviceMode)
        {
            Item[] selectedItems = null;
            if (assetType == AssetType.Script)
            {
                selectedItems = plainIncludeItem.Axes.SelectItems("./Scripts//*[@Extension='js']");
            }
            else if (assetType == AssetType.Style)
            {
                selectedItems = plainIncludeItem.Axes.SelectItems("./Styles//*[@Extension='css']");
            }

            var assets = (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Any()) ? new List<Item>(selectedItems) : new List<Item>();
            var isOptimized = true;
            switch (serviceMode)
            {
                case AssetServiceMode.Disabled:
                    assets = assets.Where(i => i.TemplateID != Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Templates.OptimizedFile.ID).ToList();
                    isOptimized = false;
                    break;
                case AssetServiceMode.Concatenate:
                case AssetServiceMode.ConcatenateAndMinify:
                    var optimizedItem = assets.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TemplateID == Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Templates.OptimizedFile.ID);
                    if (optimizedItem != null && !IsNotEmpty(optimizedItem))
                    {
                        assets = new List<Item> { optimizedItem };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        optimizedItem = new AssetBundler().GetOptimizedItem(plainIncludeItem, (OptimizationType)assetType, serviceMode);
                        if (optimizedItem != null && IsNotEmpty(optimizedItem))
                        {
                            assets = new List<Item> { optimizedItem };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            assets = new List<Item>();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            switch (assetType)
            {
                case AssetType.Script:
                    return assets.Select(s => "<script src=\"{0}\">\\x3C/script>".FormatWith(s.BuildAssetPath(isOptimized)));
                case AssetType.Style:
                    return
                        assets.Select(s => "<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />".FormatWith(s.BuildAssetPath(isOptimized)));
                default:
                    return new List<string>();
            }

        }

        private static bool IsNotEmpty(Item optimizedScriptItem)
        {
            var mediaStream = ((MediaItem)optimizedScriptItem).GetMediaStream();
            return mediaStream?.Length > 0L;
        }

        private static string GetUrlContent(AssetType assetType, string url, string joinedAttributes)
        {
            var content = string.Empty;
            if (assetType == AssetType.Script)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                {
                    content += "<script src=\"{0}\" {1}></script>".FormatWith(url, joinedAttributes);
                }
            }
            else if (assetType == AssetType.Style)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                {
                    content += "<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" {1} />".FormatWith(url, joinedAttributes);
                }
            }

            return content;
        }

        private static string GetRawContent(AssetType assetType, string rawContent)
        {
            var content = string.Empty;
            switch (assetType)
            {
                case AssetType.Script:
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawContent))
                    {
                        content += "<script>{0}</script>".FormatWith(rawContent);
                    }
                    break;
                case AssetType.Style:
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawContent))
                    {
                        content += "<style>{0}</style>".FormatWith(rawContent);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return content;
        }

        private static string GetEnumFieldValue(LookupField field)
        {
            var enumItem = field?.TargetItem;
            return enumItem?.Fields[Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Common.Templates.Enum.Fields.Value].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you get the processor working you can add it like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <assetService>
        <processor type="Westco.XA.Foundation.Theming.Pipelines.AssetService.AddPlainIncludes, Westco.XA.Foundation.Theming" />
      </assetService>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to store your script in your Sitecore instance, you could upload a script inside your theme.  It will be included automatically.  If you need it page-based, you can use the Page's Body Css Class (or ID) to only apply it to that page.  If you really must use an external file like from a CDN, you could always just [update the DOM in your custom JS file similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145914/including-a-js-file-within-a-js-file).