# Adding custom script path after assetlinks in Sxa layout file

Tags: sxa, presentation, placeholders, javascript

I have a situation where I need to add a custom `script` path after `script` paths appearing from `assetlinks.Scripts` in the `Sxa Layout` file. Tried using `placeholder` after `for loop`, but did not work out very well.
Custom script is added as `Html snippet` in `presentation details` into website `metadata partial design`

```
    @Html.Sxa().RenderRaw("<div id=\"footer\" class=\"main clearfix\">")
    @Html.Sxa().RenderRaw("...")
    @Html.Sxa().RenderRaw("</div>")
    <div id="body-bottom" class="main clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid-12">
                @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("body-bottom")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Sxa().RenderRaw("</body>")
    @Html.Sxa().RenderRaw("</html>")
</div>
@foreach (string script in assetLinks.Scripts)
{
    @Html.Raw(script)

}
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("custom-scripts")
```

This is the placeholder `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("custom-scripts")`

Can anyone suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Does this helps? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/adding-page-specific-javascript-via-sxa in Sitecore Identity Server